# Proof for this "Smoothing" lemma

Tags: integration, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

In Gerald Teschl's Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics, the author mentions the following Smoothing Lemma (0.19):

> Let $u_n(x)$ be a sequence of non-negative continuous functions on $[-1, 1]$ such that $\displaystyle{\int_{|x| \leq 1} u_n(x) dx = 1}$ and $\displaystyle{\int_{\delta \leq |x| \leq 1}u_n(x) dx} \to 0, \delta > 0$.
>
> Then for every $f \in C[-1/2, 1/2]$ which vanishes at the endpoints, $f(-1/2) = f(1/2) = 0$, we have that,
>
> $f_n(x) = \displaystyle{\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} u_n(x - y)f(y) dy}$
>
> converges uniformly to $f(x)$.

In my attempted proof, sketched below, I could not see the use for vanishing at the endpoints. Please point out if I've made a mistake.

> **Proof (My Attempt):** For fixed $n, \delta$, denote $\gamma = \displaystyle{\int_{\delta \leq |x| \leq 1} u_n(x) dx} \geq 0$; from the hypothesis, for any $\delta > 0, \gamma \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
>
> Also since $f$ is continuous on a compact interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$, $f$ is bounded, say by $M$. Then for fixed $x$ consider the integral $I$ for $f_n(x)$. By continuity, given $E$, we can find $\Delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < E$ for $|x - y| < \Delta$. Specifically $f(y) < f(x) + E$ for all $y \in [x - \Delta, x + \Delta]$. Pick $\Delta = \delta$ so that $\newcommand{\e}{\epsilon} \newcommand{\d}{\delta} \newcommand{\g}{\gamma} E < \e/2$, for arbitrary $\e > 0$. Also for this $\d$ pick $n$ so that $\g < \e/2M$. Then the said integral $I$ satisfies,
>
> $\displaystyle{I < \underbrace{M\g}_{\text{for regions} |x - y| \geq \d } + \underbrace{(f(x) + E)(1 - \g)}_{\text{for regions} |x - y| < \d}}$
>
> so $I - f(x) < M\g - f(x)\g + E(1 - \g) < M\g + E < \e$.
>
> And so, since $\e$ and $x$ was arbitrary (and crucially, $\delta = \Delta$ does not depend on $x$ as $f$ is uniformly continuous (as it is continuous on a compact interval), this holds for all $x, \e$, proving the uniform continuity?

**N.B.**: I realize I did not talk about the part where $I - f(x) > -\e$, if my mistake lies in there (i.e., the proof for that fact is not similar to the one shown), please let me know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful with signs, and try to work with absolute values instead.
Also, always put indices to indicate dependencies : $\gamma_n$ rather than just $\gamma$. That said, one cannot remove the hypothesis that $f$ vanishes at endpoints.

One can write:

$$f_n(x)-f(x)= \int_{|y-x|\geq \delta, y\in [-1/2,1/2]} u_n(x-y)f(y)dy +\int_{|y-x|< \delta,y\in [-1/2,1/2] }u_n(x-y)(f(y)-f(x))dy + f(x) \left( \int_{|y-x|<\delta,y\in [-1/2,1/2]}u_n(x-y)dy-1 \right),$$
so

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \int_{|y-x|\geq \delta} M u_n(x-y)dy + \epsilon + M \left| \left( \int_{|y-x|<\delta,y\in [-1/2,1/2]}u_n(x-y)dy-1 \right)\right|,$$
but the last term may fail to go to zero if $x=-1/2$ (or $1/2$), since in this case we are integrating 
$$\int_{-1/2}^{-1/2+\delta}u_n(-1/2-y)dy=\int_{-\delta}^{0} u_n(z)dz,$$
that may contain only half the mass of $u_n$ (if $u_n$ is even, for example).

Comment: Thanks! This is extremely clear. I will try to follow what you said, seems like I missed crucial stuff in my approximate reasoning.